# Difference between multiplication, dot product, and cross product symbols

Tags: cross-product

What is the difference between the symbols for multiplication, dot product, and cross product symbols? How can we tell them apart?

Comment: They overlap, for instance both multiplication _and_ the dot product can be represented by $\times$.  Usually a dot product is represented by $\circ$.  Generally speaking one can distinguish them through context, for instance $a\times b$ most likely means multiplication whereas $\vec{a}\times \vec{b}$ clearly is a cross product.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Often, the exact same symbol is used.
You have to pay attention to **context:**

- When you see
  $$
  x \times y
  $$
  and $x,y$ *were defined to be vectors*, it's cross product. On the other hand if $x,y$ were defined to be numbers, it's multiplication. (For that matter, the kind of multiplication depends on the kind of number they are.)
- When you see
  $$
  x \cdot y
  $$
  and $x,y$ *were defined to be vectors*, it's dot product. On the other hand if $x,y$ were defined to be numbers, it's again multiplication.

Comment: In most publications I've seen, the dot product is usually $\circ$ not $\cdot$ so there is less confusion there but I know when some (especially on this site) start talking about inner products that notation sometimes appears.

Comment: @Jared Perhaps, although personally I have seen $\cdot$ much more often. Relatedly, $\times$ for multiplication of numbers is very rare in my experience, except when dealing with literal integers or decimal numbers.

Comment: I agree with $\times$ for multiplication--that's usually discarded around elementary school.

Comment: @6005, I have never seen the $\times$ symbol for use in multiplication since elementary school with the exception of scientific notation...to be honest, they always tell us to use $\cdot$ so as to not confuse it with the variable $x$. I remember my math teacher drilled it into our heads that "thou shalt not use the $\times$ symbol for multiplication".

Comment: @heather Thanks for the anecodotes! Yeah it was the same for me, but $\times$ still does show up occasionally in various places.

Comment: In scientific notation, and as far as I know, if a variable represents a vector it has to be written in bold. So if both elements are in bold, it is a cross/dot product. If one of them is in bold and the other is not, it should be a vector with scalar multiplication. And if none of them is in bold, it should be a scalar multiplication.

Comment: concerning the dot product, it doesn't really make a difference. with two 3d vectors its `a_x * b_x  + a_y * b_y + a_z * b_z` and by 2d vectors it's `a_x * b_x  + a_y * b_y` and by regular numbers it's just `a * b`, so there is never really any confusion.